# How to restrict uploads to currently edited site

Tags: assets, upload, multi-site

I've tried

```
/{{currentSite.handle}}/
```

but this uses current site handle, not the site I'm currently editing. Is there a way to dynamically set folder to currently edited site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oli Bon from Craft Support suggested to use `{site.handle}` when you define your field (not the volume), which have worked perfectly fine.